# Ajax not work when connect with mobile data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile

My website working good in PC, but when i try to open my site from mobile with "Mobile data" then ajax request not work. But ajax work with Wifi connection.

- Ajax from PC chrome: WORK
- Ajax from mobile chrome: WORK (On Wifi)
- Ajax from mobile chrome: Not WORK (On mobile data)

Its not only my network problem, but also not work on my clients mobile data.

I have only 1 js file in my website that is JQuery 1.12.4.

Also i am using Cloudfare CDN.

**Here is my code.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  get_data();
});


function get_data(){
 var link = "URL";
  var pair = "value"; 
  var period = "value"; 

  $.ajax({
    url:link,
    type: "POST",
    data : { pairID:pair,period:period }
  }).done(function(data){
     // response in HTML Table

  });   
}
```

**Response header in PC chrome:**

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000, private, must-revalidate
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
CF-RAY:3c332594e5340e12-MXP
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sat, 25 Nov 2017 08:13:07 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:cloudflare-nginx
Set-Cookie:ci_session=879fa6e9652b84d71b75a03f5b760c42339a501b; expires=Sat, 25-Nov-2017 10:13:06 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.23
```

Request Header:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: etc
Host: www.example.com
Origin:http://www.example.com
Referer:http://www.example.com/ind?id=1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Try `hot spot share` you mobile data, and connect desktop to network via your mobile data.

Comment: I try with hotspot, wesbite load, but ajax not work, and no error return,, I test other site, also ajax not working on that site..

Comment: So you say, all website ajax include your website not working with mobile data, right? so second try, use a proxy, see it works or not. and also check `network` tab in chrome or etc, see ajax call return code is `200` or something else?

Comment: I just restart my mobile and ajax start working,,  But my clients sending me emails that ajax data not working, .. How i can fix in my clients mobile? :(

Comment: If ajax working so it's over, ignore that email

Comment: Its not 1 email, i receive more than 10 emails... Its mean almost ~100 clients are facing this issue...

Comment: So i recommend you to create new topic for this case.

Answer (score 0):

because you can use ip's in .htaccess for get, post, put. please rename it .htaccess_old it should work for all devices. #cheers